# Properly set SeekBar style for Holo and pre-Holo APIs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-seekbar

After setting `SeekBar` with Holo style, I got warning that it's not supported pre-Holo APIs.

[image]

If I leave it this way, will this crash the app or pull pre-Holo style anyway? It does not crash on the emulator and I don't have 2.3.3 device.

The reason for asking his is odd behaviour. I tried to manually set style for Holo and pre-Holo using `res/values-v11/` directories and placing `styles.xml` in each and setting the style of `SeekBar` to `style="@style/settings_seekbar"` .

Style for API 11+ looked like this

```
<style name="settings_seekbar">
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar</item>
</style>
```

and style for APIs older than 11 looked like this

```
<style name="settings_seekbar">
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.SeekBar</item>
</style>
```

So it looked like this would work. But on either device with Android 4.0+, I don't see Holo's theme, but the old thick-yellow theme.

If this is the proper way of settings styles (in case the first solution will crash  a device), where did I make a mistake thus Holo theme never appeared on newer devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we can safely use a theme from the upper SDK because I found no indicators that it will ever crash the app.

If the theme does not exist, Android will use the appropriate lower-level theme.

The error we can see on the image is just a warning that UI will not look the same in the SDKs which do not support this theme.